# load external elements in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

Is there a way to load Ionic elements at run time?

For example I have an Ionic app with a page that receives the HTML content (containing Ionic tags) from a server.

Comment: In the title you talk about external elements but in your answer you say "loading HTML from AJAX call, but with ionic2 elements". Are you talking about the rendering of external components (like web components)? Or maybe you want to render Ionic HTML at run time?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want, rendering ionic HTML at run time. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I want to use 
template: `<div [innerHTML]="myVal"></div>` 
with myVal = some ionic HTML

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue I submitted [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1156) about rendering Ionic templates at run time. As you can see in it, there are some troubles doing this for the moment and I'll not advice you to do so...